# What is the right typescript type for an event?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing, typescript, chai

Not sure if this the right place thus my question involves more contract testing than solidity but here we go:

I implemented a contract factory and spent a couple of hours figuring out how to check if the newly created child contract had the correct owner, I did manage it but as I'm using typescript my linter complains about typing issues.

Here's the contract factory code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import {Authorize} from "./utils/Authorize.sol";
import {CarBooklet} from "./CarBooklet.sol";

contract CarBookletProvider is Authorize {
    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    event BookletCreated(address bookletAddr);

    function provide(address bookletOwner)
        external
        isOwner
    {
        CarBooklet booklet = new CarBooklet(bookletOwner);
        emit BookletCreated(address(booklet));
    }
}
```

Here's the test:

```
        it("Should create a booklet with an owner", async function () {

            const { carBookletProvider, owner, otherAccount } = await loadFixture(deployCarBookletProviderFixture);
            await carBookletProvider.provide(otherAccount.address);
            const events = await carBookletProvider.queryFilter("BookletCreated");
            const CarBooklet = await ethers.getContractFactory("CarBooklet");
            const carBooklet = await CarBooklet.attach(events[0].args[0]);

            expect(await carBooklet.owner()).to.equal(otherAccount.address);
        });
```

And the linter complains about this line

```
const events = await carBookletProvider.queryFilter("BookletCreated");
```

with the following message:

> Le type '"BookletCreated"' n'a aucune propriété en commun avec le type 'TypedEventFilter<TypedEvent<any, any>>

the BookletCreated type does not have any common property with the TypedEventFilter<TypedEvent<any, any>> type.

This test works fine but I want to do things the right way. What would be the right parameter type for the queryFilter function instead of the string I'm currently using?

And one more question, is it the best way to make such a test? In my first attempts, I tried to make the provide function return the newly generated contract address like in this snippet:

```
    function provide(address bookletOwner)
        external
        isOwner
        returns(CarBooklet booklet)
    {
        booklet = new CarBooklet(bookletOwner);
        emit BookletCreated(address(booklet));
    }
```

but then in the testing script I tried this to get the transaction result:

```
const tx = await carBookletProvider.provide(otherAccount.address);
const result = await tx.wait();
```

And I expected the contractAddress attribute to have some value but instead it is always set to null, then I thought that the test has to wait for the creation event to be emitted, so I add the following line

```
carBookletProvider.on("BookletCreated", (args) => {
    // do the contract connection here
});
```

but the listener is never trigerred for some reason, thus I opted for the solution I showed you earlier.

Summary:

1. Which type do I need to use for the queryFilter function using typescript?
2. Why the contractAddress attribute is always null in the transaction results and am I wrong when I try to listen for the BookletCreated event like I did in the snippet above?

Thanks for your time reading.

Comment: 2- Transactions work in a way that for returning the value the transaction has to be executed. It is possible to design an API that outputs the returned value but using events was the preferred solution in the early days, and now it is hard to change. 1- Sorry, but I can't help you with typescript.

Comment: Thanks  for your answer though, so ok using events is the best way to go. Makes sense as it's more practical.